# How to load JavaScript intermixed with html

Tags: javascript, iframe

So I need to pull some JavaScript out of a remote page that has (worthless) HTML combined with (useful) JavaScript.  The page, call it, http://remote.com/data.html, looks something like this (crazy I know):

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="/images/a.gif" />
    <div>blah blah blah</div><br/><br/>
    var data = { date: "2009-03-15", data: "Some Data Here" };

</body>
</html>
```

so, I need to load this data variable in my local page and use it.

I'd prefer to do so with completely client-side code.  I figured, if I could get the HTML of this page into a local JavaScript variable, I could parse out the JavaScript code, run `eval` on it and be good to use the data.  So I thought load the remote page in an iframe, but I can't seem to find the iframe in the DOM. Why not?:

```
<script>
    alert(window.parent.frames.length);
    alert(document.getElementById('my_frame'));
</script>

<iframe name="my_frame" id='my_frame' style='height:1px; width:1px;' frameBorder=0 src='http://remote.com/data.html'></iframe>
```

The first alert shows `0`, the second `null`, which makes no sense.  How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Careful what you wish for - if all that succeeds, you (and your users!) will be running untrusted code (if it's not under your control, it could change anytime) in the context of your page. Drive-by malware, anyone?

Comment: Of course the alert's will show 0 and null... When that script runs the iframe doesn't exist yet... Put the script tag below the iframe element..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried switching the order - i.e. iframe first, script next? The script runs before the iframe is inserted into the DOM.

Also, this worked for me in a similar situation: give the iframe an onload handler:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/blah" onload="do_some_stuff_with_the_iframe()"></iframe>
```

Last but not least, pay attention to the cross-site scripting issues - the iframe may be loaded, but your JS may not be allowed to access it.

Comment: using onload() worked, but as you suspected, I'm running into xss issues now.  I guess I'll have to use some kind of server side solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use XMLHttpRequest to retrieve the page, although it is [apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-site_HTTP_requests) only currently being implemented for cross-site requests.

I understand that you might want to make a tool that used the client's internet connection to retrieve the html page (for security or legal reasons), so it is a legitimate hope.

If you do end up needing to do it server-side, then perhaps a simple php page that takes a url as a query and returns a json chunk containing the script in a string. That way if you do find you need to filter out certain websites, you need only do this in one place.

The inevitable problem is that some of the users will be hostile, and they then have a license to abuse what is effectively a javascript proxy. As a result, the safest option may be to do all the processing on the server, and not allow certain javascript function calls (eval, http requests, etc).